# BattlesHISTORY citation problem

Tags: bibliographies

This is a minimal code for the earlier BattlesHISTORY problem: it's doing that for every citation, unless I have a `\parencite` inline command. I hope this helps.  I have spent a lot of time. Thanks.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
   
\title{ABC}
\author{XYZ}
\date{15 08 2020}
\begin{document}
American Revolutionary.\cite{BattlesHISTORY} 

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{BattlesHISTORY,
  title = {{Battles of Lexington and Concord - HISTORY}},
  url = {https://www.history.com/topics/american-revolution/battles-of-lexington-and-concord}
}
\end{filecontents*}
   
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Again its all jumbled up. THank you all but I am tired of this.

Comment: This should have been an edit to the previous one not a new post, no harm done but can you delete the original question as this is just the same question.

Comment: Deleted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see in the `biblatex-mla` manual, the style doesn't support `@misc`.

Also, the argument to `\addbibresource` should contain the actual `.bib` file you want to be read, in this case `\jobname.bib`. For your production version, it might be `references.bib` or whatever name you have.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{BattlesHISTORY,
  title = {Battles of {Lexington} and {Concord} -- {HISTORY}},
  url = {https://www.history.com/topics/american-revolution/battles-of-lexington-and-concord}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\title{ABC}
\author{XYZ}
\date{15 08 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

American Revolutionary~\autocite{BattlesHISTORY}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I used `article` just to get a single page for the image.

[image]

If you add `\usepackage{hyperref}`, then “Web” becomes a hyperlink pointing to the requested site.

Comment: This helped a lot.   Been only several hours for me on LATEX. Thank you. But this means that the Mendeley integration needs a lot of improvement. Because the keys are being fed/ synced by Mendeley. SO even after a paid service, I have to edit them manually. Just saying. But Thanks Again.